# Inner workings of GRASS reclassification on QGIS. How does it work with multiband rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify, multi-band, qgis-grass-plugin

I have a 33 band raster layer I need to reclassify. I tried using GRASS module inside QGIS and it worked out fine, except that it outputs a raster with a single band. Which band of the 33 did it reclassified? Does it make some kind of merging to take into account all 33 bands? I tried reading GRASS' reclass manual, but it doesn't mention multiband rasters or any similar situation.